# base64 encode length parameter

Tags: ruby, base64

I am decoding a base64 string, modifying it, and re-encoding it with Ruby. The problem when I re-encode it is that the ruby encode library is adding a linebreak after 60 or so characters. How can I tell it to not have max characters per line limit?

```
val = "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"

decoded_val = Base64.decode64(val)
encoded_val = Base64.encode64(val)

#=> QmFzZTY0IGlzIGEgZ2VuZXJpYyB0ZXJtIGZvciBhIG51bWJlciBvZiBzaW1p
#   bGFyIGVuY29kaW5nIHNjaGVtZXMgdGhhdCBlbmNvZGUgYmluYXJ5IGRhdGEg
#   YnkgdHJlYXRpbmcgaXQgbnVtZXJpY2FsbHkgYW5kIHRyYW5zbGF0aW5nIGl0
#   IGludG8gYSBiYXNlIDY0IHJlcHJlc2VudGF0aW9uLiBUaGUgQmFzZTY0IHRl
#   cm0gb3JpZ2luYXRlcyBmcm9tIGEgc3BlY2lmaWMgTUlNRSBjb250ZW50IHRy
#   YW5zZmVyIGVuY29kaW5nLg0KDQpCYXNlNjQgZW5jb2Rpbmcgc2NoZW1lcyBh
#   cmUgY29tbW9ubHkgdXNlZCB3aGVuIHRoZXJlIGlzIGEgbmVlZCB0byBlbmNv
#   ZGUgYmluYXJ5IGRhdGEgdGhhdCBuZWVkcyBiZSBzdG9yZWQgYW5kIHRyYW5z
#   ZmVycmVkIG92ZXIgbWVkaWEgdGhhdCBhcmUgZGVzaWduZWQgdG8gZGVhbCB3
#   aXRoIHRleHR1YWwgZGF0YS4gVGhpcyBpcyB0byBlbnN1cmUgdGhhdCB0aGUg
#   ZGF0YSByZW1haW5zIGludGFjdCB3aXRob3V0IG1vZGlmaWNhdGlvbiBkdXJp
#   bmcgdHJhbnNwb3J0LiBCYXNlNjQgaXMgdXNlZCBjb21tb25seSBpbiBhIG51
#   bWJlciBvZiBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnMgaW5jbHVkaW5nIGVtYWlsIHZpYSBNSU1F
#   LCBhbmQgc3RvcmluZyBjb21wbGV4IGRhdGEgaW4gWE1MLg==
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not because of your terminal? Just tried it, it works without line breaks for me

Comment: On windows 7 command prompt I have my width set to 300 when I put the string the first time there's no line breaks but after the base64 it seems to be there

Comment: Did you try to output it to a file to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Anthony: The "try it and see what happens" approach is a recipe for disaster, especially when interoperability is concerned. There are documented standards for these things and they're not terribly difficult to find.

Comment: @mu I wasn't aware of these specifications therefore I thought it was some kind of display issue. That's I wanted to see if outputting to a file would make a difference. Good thing you came across this post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RFC 4648: The Base16, Base32, and Base64 Data Encodings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.3) has this to say:

> **3.3.  Interpretation of Non-Alphabet Characters in Encoded Data**
> [...]
> Implementations MUST reject the encoded data if it contains
> characters outside the base alphabet when interpreting base-encoded
> data, unless the specification referring to this document explicitly
> states otherwise.  Such specifications may instead state, as MIME
> does, that characters outside the base encoding alphabet should
> simply be ignored when interpreting data ("be liberal in what you
> accept").  Note that this means that any adjacent carriage return/
> line feed (CRLF) characters constitute "non-alphabet characters" and
> are ignored.

So the newlines are fine and pretty much everything will ignore them even if they're not strictly compliant with RFC 4648.

Also, the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-decode64) has this to say:

> **encode64(bin)**
>
> Returns the Base64-encoded version of `bin`. This method complies with RFC 2045. Line feeds are added to every 60 encoded charactors [sic].

So the 60 character line length is intentional and specified. If you want strict RFC 4648 Base64 (i.e. no newlines), then there is [`strict_encode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64):

> **strict_encode64(bin)**
>
> Returns the Base64-encoded version of `bin`. This method complies with RFC 4648. No line feeds are added.

So you can say `Base64.strict_encode64(val)` to get the output you're looking for.

And for reference, here's the [relevant section of RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.8):

> **6.8.  Base64 Content-Transfer-Encoding**
> [...]
> The encoded output stream must be represented in lines of no more
> than 76 characters each.  All line breaks or other characters not
> found in Table 1 must be ignored by decoding software.

So the 60 character line length is somewhat arbitrary but compliant with RFC 2045 since `60 < 76`.

Comment: "If you don't want strict ..." then use "strict..."? That sounds strange. I don't think that not having line feeds do not strictly comply to the standard. Your "If you don't want strict ..." is misleading.

Comment: @sawa: The *don't* was my hands not typing what my brain was telling them to, fixed. Thanks for the heads up.