# Base64 encoding, new line after 60 chars vs new line after 76 chars

Tags: json, ruby, shell, ruby-on-rails-5

**Before u start reading all my long post** I figured it out why it doesnt work. Its about base64, it adds new line after each 60chars by default. This link : [base64 encode length parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301708/base64-encode-length-parameter) 
is a bit explenation. Is there Base64 module which adds new line after every 76 chars ?

**So solution** is just this

```
@checkout_signature = Base64.strict_encode64(@signature + "|" + checkout_request)
@checkout_signature = @checkout_signature.insert(76, "\n") # once 
or 
@checkout_signature.gsub!(/.{76}(?=.)/, '\0'+"\n") # every 76 chars
```

Please help me translate this bash script to ruby in proper way. Actually just base64 encoding is bad

**UPDATE**

bash way

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Signature test'
export checkout_request='{"charge":{"amount":499,"currency":"EUR"}}'
echo $checkout_request
export signature=`echo -n "$checkout_request" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac 'pr_test_tXHm9qV9qV9bjIRHcQr9PLPa' | sed 's/^.* //'`
echo $signature
echo '--------'
echo -n "$signature|$checkout_request" | base64
```

RESULT

```
{"charge":{"amount":499,"currency":"EUR"}}
cf9ce2d8331c531f8389a616a18f9578c134b784dab5cb7e4b5964e7790f173c
--------
Y2Y5Y2UyZDgzMzFjNTMxZjgzODlhNjE2YTE4Zjk1NzhjMTM0Yjc4NGRhYjVjYjdlNGI1OTY0ZTc3
OTBmMTczY3x7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=
Y2Y5Y2UyZDgzMzFjNTMxZjgzODlhNjE2YTE4Zjk1NzhjMTM0Yjc4NGRhYjVjYjdlNGI1OTY0ZTc3OTBmMTczY3x7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=
```

ruby way

```
checkout_request='{"charge":{"amount":499,"currency":"EUR"}}'
secret_key ='pr_test_tXHm9qV9qV9bjIRHcQr9PLPa'

@signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', secret_key, checkout_request);
puts @signature;
puts "-----"
@checkout_signature = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(@signature + "|" + checkout_request)
puts @checkout_signature
```

RESULT

```
cf9ce2d8331c531f8389a616a18f9578c134b784dab5cb7e4b5964e7790f173c
-----
ODY4YzY4YTg4NmFmOTg2MGY5OGVjMmUyODM5OTBhYmViNmQyZjUzYWI5ZjgxMzlhYzFlODllNThhZTVhZTFkMnx7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=
```

**UPDATE**
ok signature is ok, but I use bad base64 encoding....

**SOMEHOW**

`echo -n "$signature|$checkout_request" | base64`
adds newline after $signature

and its the only '\n' in bash result

in ruby when i use `.encode64` i get many more n's
`"Y2Y5Y2UyZDgzMzFjNTMxZjgzODlhNjE2YTE4Zjk1NzhjMTM0Yjc4NGRhYjVj\nYjdlNGI1OTY0ZTc3OTBmMTczY3x7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwi\nY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=\n"`

when I use `.strict_encode64` or `.urlsafe_encode64` there is no `\n`
`"Y2Y5Y2UyZDgzMzFjNTMxZjgzODlhNjE2YTE4Zjk1NzhjMTM0Yjc4NGRhYjVjYjdlNGI1OTY0ZTc3OTBmMTczY3x7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0="`

and result from bash looks like this
`Y2Y5Y2UyZDgzMzFjNTMxZjgzODlhNjE2YTE4Zjk1NzhjMTM0Yjc4NGRhYjVjYjdlNGI1OTY0ZTc3
OTBmMTczY3x7ImNoYXJnZSI6eyJhbW91bnQiOjQ5OSwiY3VycmVuY3kiOiJFVVIifX0=`

there must be newline after c3, that's the way `pritnenv` shows variable.I  can't inspect it like in ruby

**WHY THERE IS SUCH DIFFERENCE**

Comment: Try `pre_request.gsub('"', '')`

Comment: i tried, no success. then it looses all quotes. I know that somehow string needs to know that its not over and posts \ before quote.

Comment: `signature.chop` - removes the last character

Comment: bardzo zabawne :)

Comment: Any advice appreciated